# How to play random part of mp4 file with vlc or something else?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, vlc, libvlc

I have random part (99,9% somewhere in the middle) of the mp4 file. Problem is that it's not in any container or anything just a binary piece of the file in random offset and send to me... it will keep growing but it'll take a while and I need to play content right away.

I can get all necessary metadata information for that file from other source before I even start receiving those binary data, but:

1. How to do this? I mean what headers do I need and how to get them? 
   and
2. How to later tell vlc (or maybe some other player) that this moov atom (or some other data) that it should use for this part of the file and start playing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've solved it like this (dirty workaround):
Coppied the moov part (just looking for this atom) from oryginal file and created the file of the oryginal size filling with zeros and the metadata parts. Than I'm simply running player and jump with it to part that is already downloaded. 
(still having problems how to find where to jump based on binary offset, but proportions of files seems to work quite ok with it, however the keyframe is often lost and artefacts are for quite some time, also the color is off for few seconds)

But I'm still interested with more elegant solutions.